# Clonezilla sees external USB drive, but won't offer it as destination in partition to partition clone?

Tags: linux, ssd, clone, clonezilla

I'm trying to clone a single bootable partition on my Ubuntu Linux 16.04 system to a new SSD in an external USB container.  I want the new SSD drive to be bootable.  Clonezilla definitely sees the destination drive, the external USB drive with that has the ID "**sdd**", when it loads up.  It also sees "sdd" as a potential destination if I enter disk-to-disk clone mode.  However, it **does not** see "sdd" when I go into partiton-to-partition mode.  It only lists the internal partitions (sdb1/sdb2/etc.) when offering me the list of destinations t choose from.  It absolutely does not offer "sdd" as a potential destination for the partition-to-partition cloning operation.

I can't use disk-to-disk clone because the source disk is a dual boot disk with Windows and Linux on it, and *their combined size is larger than the destination disk*.  However, the Linux partition I am trying to on the destination disk is much smaller than the destination drive "**sdd**".  How can I get Clonezilla to see "sdd", the external USB drive, as a potential destination and offer it to me as the destination for the cloning operation?

Comment: Did you create an empty partition on the SSD to clone to? Sounds like it wants to see one first. It's not a "partition to partition" clone if there isn't a destination partition. Also you mentioned it is dual boot. If the partition you are trying to clone is not curently the "active" partition, then it's not bootable and won't work if cloned by itself.

Comment: @Appleoddity So I need to make a partition on the destination device.  Ok.  That would explain it.  I didn't see an option to do that from within Clonezilla so I'll have to boot back into Linux and do that.  Thanks.

Comment: @Robert Did you find any solution?